# Mapping JSON objects in Java

Tags: javascript, java, json, jackson, nashorn

What is the best way to map JSON objects in Java? I'm talking about something like Dozer or MapStruct for JavaBeans but for JSON. I found these two projects:

[JSON Mapper 1](https://github.com/dregenor/jsonMapper)

[JSON Mapper 2](https://github.com/onechiporenko/json-mapper)

But they are in Javascript. So is it a good idea to embed them in my Java application running them with Nashorn? Or is it better to use straightforward Jackson library? But the second would imply reading the JSON, mapping it to a Java object and then converting the Java Object to another JSON - seems not very nice to me.

Comment: you can use json.simple for mapping

Comment: or else you can also use this one https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json/20180130

Comment: Using these packages would mean to convert JSON to a Java object and to convert it to another JSON after that, as far as I understand. Is that correct?

Comment: yea, go through the doc, you will get an idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't map from JSON to JSON in Java because JSON is not a native data type. At some point, you have to parse the JSON into a representation that is understood by Java in order to work with it.

You don't need to marshal it into Java objects, though. You can read the JSON tree (with Jackson, GSON, etc) which will be an object-oriented representation of the JSON string. From there, you can construct your desired JSON output.

Comment: And what about the way through JavaScript libraries I listed? Does it make sense?

Comment: Probably not. I don't know much about them, but embedding JS in your Java application is introducing a whole additional level of complexity and overhead that is almost certainly not worth it for the small task you need to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

There are some java libraries doing the JSON mapping kind of Dozer or MapStruct:

[Silencio](https://github.com/damianszczepanik/silencio)

[Sawmill](https://github.com/logzio/sawmill/wiki/JSON-Processor)

[Jolt](https://github.com/bazaarvoice/jolt)